# How to fire the OnUserJoined event when a user connects to channel without broadcasting role

Tags: agora.io

Im using the React Native integration of AgoraSDK and i have noticed that the `onUserJoined` event only fires if the user connects as a broadcaster. Does anyone know how to fire it if the user is connected only as Audience? thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Short anwser

In broadcasting mode, there is no callback to notify the client when a audience joined.

#### Something you can do

If you really want the client to get such informations, try following ways:

- Use communication mode.
- Or, implement your own callback, let you signaling server notify the client in such situation.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, from your comment I ended up implementing the second option, just created a quick backend that will send the signal to the channel when a user joins and adds the user info to the list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "peer-online" event. It triggers when a remote user or host joins the channel and manipulate that in that running session.

```
client.on('peer-online', function(evt) {
  console.log('peer-online', evt.uid);
});
```

You can have a look at, https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/web/interfaces/agorartc.client.html#join

this may help you, Thanks